# C++ OpenCV imread with CV_8UC4 halved size

Tags: c++, opencv, png, imread

We are trying to read a PNG image of size 400x400 using OpenCV 4.1.0 calling:

```
*image = imread( filepath, CV_8UC4 );
```

When I print both cols and rows of the mat calling:

`printf("col: %d , rows: %d \n", image->cols, image->rows);`

it shows

`col: 200, rows: 200`

But calling `file` on the picture it shows:

`PNG image data, 400 x 400, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced`.

When I try to put the pic on a second one, it shows that the size is of the picture wrong indeed.

How can I force the reading of the picture giving a 400x400 Mat of `Vec4b`.

Comment: `CV_8UC4` doesn't make sense there. Use `IMREAD_UNCHANGED` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument of `imread` is `flags` argument, which expects some color loading flags but not pixel type as you provide. Read possible `flags` values and their meaning [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-alpha/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#imread).

Instead load the image as is, and if it does not contain 4 channels or the type is not what you want, recombine channels (with OpenCV `split()`, `merge()`, `mixChannels()` etc.) and convert it to needed pixel type with `cv::Mat::convertTo()`. Or use legal `imread` flags if any of them suits your needs.